# Else statement not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to return the longest even word in the array using a forEach loop and return "00" when there is no even word. I am able to get the part of returning the longest even word to work correctly, but when I introduce the else statement it doesn't work anymore:

```
function FindlongestWord(input) {
  var arrWords = input.split(' ');
  var wordlength = 0;
  var word = '';
  arrWords.forEach(function(wrd) {
    if (wordlength < wrd.length && wrd.length % 2 == 0) {
      wordlength = wrd.length;
      word = wrd;
    } else  {
      return "00";
    }
  });
  return word;
}
```

Comment: else  {
    word="00"; } try this

Comment: @baao That doesn't work; it will reset the currently found word to "00" whenever a word isn't longer and even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `return "00"` statement only returns from the inner function and not from `FindlongestWord(input)` function.

you can initialize your word with "00". then it will return "00" if it is not set inside forEach.

```
function FindlongestWord(input) {
var arrWords = input.split(' ');
var wordlength = 0;
var word = '00';
arrWords.forEach(function(wrd) {
   if (wordlength < wrd.length && wrd.length % 2 == 0) {
      wordlength = wrd.length;
      word = wrd;
   }
});
return word;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisG is the first sentence wrong? doesn't it return from the inner function?

Comment: @Dij Yes it does, but you make it sound like Tom's intention was to return "00" from the outer function, which I don't think was his intention at all. The problem with `else return "00"` isn't that it doesn't return from the outer function, the problem is that it overwrites a previously found longest word.

Comment: Actually OP's intention is to return "00" from the outer function if he can't find any word with even length as he has stated in his question if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Dij YES, but unless he says otherwise, I'll assume he's smart enough to realize that returning from the outer function after a single failed test is nonsense.

Comment: @ChrisG I believe thats where the mistake was. He wanted to return '00' and he used `return '00'` inside else condition, which makes it wrong.

Comment: Not sure how else to put it. I think he made a basic mistake, you think he made a really stupid mistake *and* a basic mistake. Let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

As others already explained: The `forEach` function ignores the return value of the callback function, so it is useless to return '00' there.

Here is another solution that uses `filter` and `reduce` instead of `forEach`. It does not need to hold and update variables outside of the callbacks:

```
function FindLongestEvenWord(input) {
    var arrWords = input.split(' ');
    var r = arrWords.filter(function(w) {
            return w.length % 2 == 0;
        }).reduce(function(res, w) {
            return (w.length > res.length) ? w : res;
        }, "");
    return r == "" ? "00" : r;
}
```